# Are Syms and Symsum slow?

Tags: matlab, debugging

Im working on a huge matlab code in which I have a symbolic function G as well as its inverse invG and first derivative g defined using "syms" and I use "matlabFunction" in certain functions. These symbolic functions are called multiple times within various functions in the code. The problem is that my code is toooo slow and I suspect the symbolic functions are to blame.
Im also using "symsum" for some convergent series and sums.

Comment: Yes it is slow. Do you know that you can profile your code? i.e. you can know what exactly takes longer. Click on the "run and time" icon on the topbar

Comment: Symbolic math is very different from numeric math and is usually much slower. Consider if you even need to use symbolic math (vs. not knowing how to implement something numerically). And re-write your code to not call the symbolic unctions multiple times. Other than that, your question is not specific enough for us to provide any real help.